# Android app not running from market but pushing apk works

Tags: java, android, runtime-error

I have created an app the past could of days which has been great so far. I published app to play store and all worked fine.

Last night I uploaded an upgrade version with a few minor changes, when I try to install the app from the market it doesnt work I get ClassNotFoundException as soon as the main activity starts. If I run the app directly from eclipse or I push the compiled APK to the device over adb it works fine.

Has anyone seen this before, its a new one on me.

As per advice on IRC ProGuard is commented out in the properties file.

Comment: Post the logcat with stacktrace and any other errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more information from logcat (with the android market version), the best guess to try is:

1. uninstall any versions of your app on your device and redownload it again
2. export into signed APK and directly push that onto your device with the "adb install MY_APP.apk" and see if that app works. (then make SURE you upload this particular one APK, and not some other one by accident)